# Is it okay for the graduate school if my fall semester GPA drops?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gpa

I am an undergraduate student and just submitted the applications to the grad schools in both the US and the UK. This semester has been really tough for me, and I feel like my overall GPA might be dropping by a little (from 3.95 to around 3.91). I am worried about if the grad school admission office will be harsh on my grade, especially in one class I enrolled in this semester, I feel like the grade might be 3.0/4.0. Am I worrying too much about that? Do I need to be prepared to explain anything if there's an interview? Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You know that's like a 1% change, right?

Comment: 'Worries' avoid walking on the rationality street.

Comment: Will the schools you've applied to know what your fall semester grades are if you've already submitted the applications? Or are these applications that you will submit only after those grades are determined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are worrying too much. It is actually pretty common for grades to drop somewhat in the final term. Students have a lot on their minds.

In the US, at least, any single data point is unlikely to make much of any difference as the evaluation is broad based. And there is nothing problematic about 3.9x grades in any case. And a single course grade is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Indeed, a drop in the 3rd significant figure is, well, insignificant. Now, a semester of all C's or worse is another thing...